# If a set $A$ is a Borel set, is the union of all line segments from some point $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ to the points in $A$ a Borel set?

Tags: measure-theory

Specifically, if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is a Borel set, is the set $C_{x,A}=\{at+x(1-t)|t\in[0,1],a\in A\}$ a Borel set if $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$? Is the set $C_{x,A,\infty}=\{at+x(1-t)|t\in[0,\infty),a\in A\}$ Borel?